# asp.net EPPlus PageRequestManagerParserErrorException error

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, epplus

I have an UpdatePanel with a dynamically created table and I am trying to use the save stream as excel function of EPPlus. However I keep getting an error when I call my `SaveToExcel()` method.

The method works fine if I have it in an empty website so I believe it has something to do with the postback/UpdatePanel.

The error:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed.
```

The code causing the error from the [dynamic]:

```
function Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_endPostBack(error, executor, data) {
        if (this._request === executor.get_webRequest()) {
            this._processingRequest = false;
            this._additionalInput = null;
            this._request = null;
        }
        var handler = this._get_eventHandlerList().getHandler("endRequest");
        var errorHandled = false;
        if (handler) {
            var eventArgs = new Sys.WebForms.EndRequestEventArgs(error, data ? data.dataItems : {}, executor);
            handler(this, eventArgs);
            errorHandled = eventArgs.get_errorHandled();
        }
        if (error && !errorHandled) {
            throw error;
        }
    }
```

This is how i end my `SaveToExcel()` method:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=Bulk Swap HDDs.xlsx");
package.SaveAs(Response.OutputStream);
Response.End();
```

Is there something really obvious I'm missing? If I place the `SaveToExcel` into another aspx page and just do a `PostBackUrl="~/SaveToExcel.aspx"`, it also works fine (but then my submit button crashes).

Comment: Use firebug/Browser utility e.g. Fiddler to see the returned result in HttpResponse. There must be some server side error that's why you're getting the parse exception.

Comment: I have tried placing the buttons outside the update panel as per here: http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/02/26/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it.aspx and that error is gone but thi spart no longer works: btnSubmit.OnClientClick = @"parent.location='\\\\server\\folder\\" + us.Substring(pos, us.Length - pos).Trim() + ".bat'"; I just need to be able to open a file from another server onbutton click